# iview-ui in English language?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, iview-ui

The official docs of iview are mostly in Chinese.

This link [iview Installation](https://www.iviewui.com/docs/guide/install-en) contains code which is in English but when you run the code, the modal options - "Cancel" is showing in Chinese.

Is there any way to fix that, I mean convert it to English?

[image]

I tried to follow this link from [Github issue](https://github.com/iview/iview/issues/1983) but it was for NodeJS.
I want to make it work without NodeJS.

Comment: It's all in the docs https://www.iviewui.com/components/modal-en

Comment: @Molda please see the picture first. I asked about those options, from where they came in Chinese?

Comment: @RupamDotInfo did you get it working?

Comment: @Molda I think this question is about i18n and not template sintax.

Comment: @Sergio you are right that it's possible to use Locales ( i din't know about that ) but there are also `okText` and `cancelText` props of the modal that can be used for english text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the Locale you want to use. I'm using English and Swedish settings for example.

You can do this like:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import iView from 'iview';
import locale from 'iview/dist/locale/en-US';
Vue.use(iView, {locale: locale});
```

This way all components will use English text.

Comment: I want to use it as just a JavaScript library with PHP server, not with NodeJS.

Comment: @RupamDotInfo ok, so you want to load the Locale settings in the browser directly? How are you compiling the templates/`.vue` files?

Comment: I am not using any .vue file, I'm just using it inside HTML using their CDN to load those .css and .js files. From this example - https://www.iviewui.com/docs/guide/install-en

Comment: @RupamDotInfo this is what you look for right? http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/ns62o63L/

Comment: exactly this, so what is the minimal JavaScript code for English language? http://jsfiddle.net/ns62o63L/1/

Comment: @RupamDotInfo the minimum depends on what components you use. But I suggest you use the whole object, its very little compared with the Vue.js library file anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Use with CDN:

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/iview/dist/iview.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/iview/dist/locale/en-US.js"></script>
<script>
  iview.lang('en-US');
</script>
```

For more language options see [here](https://www.iviewui.com/docs/guide/i18n-en)